# How to generate a Windows executable using pyinstaller on Linux?

Tags: python, executable, pyinstaller

I'm trying to generate an executable from Linux for Windows using pyinstaller.

```
pyinstaller --onefile --windowed montecarlo.py
```

I run this command and get a single executable that works on Linux just fine, but if I try on Windows, it's just a simple file. Why?

Comment: Please clarify. What is the extension of the generated file?

Comment: On Linux it's a `executable (application/x-executable)`, but on Windows it's a `Type of file: File`

Answer (score 6):

I was trying to do this same thing today and ran across [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/740016). It pointed to [the FAQ](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/wiki/FAQ), which says cross-compiling is not supported. It recommends using Wine.

Comment: Did you ever get this off the ground? I'd like to be able to build windows releases in pipelines (which run linux docker containers).